# How to have a layout next to TextView such that it will always be visible and close to the textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, textview

As seen in picture below I need a layout where Textview containing contents 'Hello' and layout '2' are always visible and are between layout '1' and ']'

```
{1}Hello{2}    ]
```

```
{1}Hello I..{2}]
```

If textview contents are too long they should ellipsize
Layout '2' shouldn't be right aligned to parent or ']', but be next to TextView

I have tried playing with wieghts and relative layout but do not seem to get a working solution.

Any ideas/pointers?

Here is slimdown version of my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/simple_white_button"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/headshot_alt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/myRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photo" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="New Jersey"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_text"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/weather"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left" >

                <!-- Weather -->

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgWeather"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_notification_news"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtWeather"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="50/43"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_dark"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:background="@drawable/simple_white_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_quickaction_default" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where {1} would be the id = photo, ] is id=menu and id=myRow is the textview + weather layout i want in between photo and menu. I preferably do not want to set max width on my address text view, in worst case i want it ellipsize when weather touches the menu, But when address is small i want weather next to address and not close to menu

Hopefully its bit more clear now

Answer (score 0):

In a relative layout, with fixed width for the textview, Layout'2' as layout_toRightOf the textview, something like this:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstText"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Hello String"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layoutTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstText"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Layout 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Provide the container layout as per your requirement. With a fill_parent width, you can adjust the "]" to be at the extreme right or xdp away after your Layout 2
Can you specify, precisely, what is required...i'l edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I have added some more info in my post, I would like the textview to not have fixed width, it should be small if data is less and take parent width-weather layout width if address is too long

Comment: @aarati  can you post a screenshot of what is happening and mark it with what is required, from the xml...if you want your textview ellipsized..i think it'l happen only if there is some fixed width or mentioned that it should be a limited num of lines with certain width. Placing the "]" at extreme right would otherwise get what you want, without playing around with weights